# extract each line followed by a line with a different value in column two

Tags: bash, awk, sed, extract

Given the following file structure,

```
9.975   1.49000000      0.295   0       0.4880  0.4929  0.5113  0.5245  2.016726        1.0472  -30.7449        1
9.975   1.49000000      0.295   1       0.4870  0.5056  0.5188  0.5045  2.015859        1.0442  -30.7653        1
9.975   1.50000000      0.295   0       0.5145  0.4984  0.4873  0.5019  2.002143        1.0854  -30.3044        2
```

is there a way to extract each line in which the value in column two is not equal to the value in column two in the following line?
I.e. from these three lines I would like to extract the second one, since 1.49 is not equal to 1.50.
Maybe with sed or awk?

This is how I do this in MATLAB:

```
myline = 1;
mynewline = 1;
while myline < length(myfile)
    if myfile(myline,2) ~= myfile(myline+1,2)
        mynewfile(mynewline,:) = myfile(myline,:);
        mynewline = mynewline+1;
        myline = myline+1;
    else
        myline = myline+1;
    end
end
```

However, my files are so large now that I would prefer to carry out this extraction in terminal before transferring them to my laptop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Awk should do.

```
<data awk '($2 != prev) {print line} {line = $0; prev = $2}'
```

A brief intro to awk: awk program consists of a set of `condition {code}` blocks. It operates line by line. When no condition is given, the block is executed for each line. `BEGIN` condition is executed before the first line. Each line is split to fields, which are accessible with `$_number_`. The full line is in `$0`.

Here I compare the second field to the previous value, if it does not match I `print` the whole previous line. In all cases I store the current line into `line` and the second field into `prev`.

And if you really want it right, careful with the float comparisons - something like `abs($2 - prev) < eps` (there is no `abs` in awk, you need to define it yourself, and eps is some small enough number). I'm actually not sure if awk converts to number for equality testing, if not you're safe with the string comparisons.

Comment: The first line is not needed - from the example above, only the second one. Could you explain more on the function of your command? I'm trying to test it right now but nothing happens.

Comment: You did not specify where your data is, so I defaulted to stdin. To actually use it you need to put your data in a file with some name, say `data` and then do `<data awk ...`.

Comment: Ah, got it - but it prints the third line from the example above. As far as I understand this line, this is what happens: we initially take -1 as a reference, than go through column number 2 and compare each value to the reference. in case the values do not match, the current line is printed and the reference value is set to the value from column 2 in this line. now I only need to figure out how to make it print the previous line!

Comment: Umm, sorry misread the question:) Just store the full line (`$0`) and output it conditionally. Will fix it.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 'N;/^((\S+)\s+){2}.*\n\S+\s+\2/!P;D' file
```

Read two lines at a time. Pattern match on the first two columns and only print the first line when the second column does not match.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to modify this command to print (in case the second column does not match) not only the first line, but the last n lines?

Comment: @Ango I don't understand your comment. Examples speak better than words.

Comment: Not enough space in the comments for examples :) I would like to know how to modify this command such that it would do the following: Read two lines at a time. Pattern match on the first two columns and only print the first line **and it's preceding line** when the second column does not match. I guess one would need to read three lines at a time i.o. to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Try following command:

```
awk '$2 != field && field { print line } { field = $2; line = $0 }' infile
```

It saves previous line and second field, comparing in next loop with current line values. The `&& field` check is useful to avoid a blank line at the beginning of file, when `$2 != field` would match because variable is empty.

It yields:

```
9.975   1.49000000      0.295   1       0.4870  0.5056  0.5188  0.5045  2.015859        1.0442  -30.7653        1
```

Comment: It almost works! Just one thing, I can't figure it out: this command yields two out of three lines which need to be extracted from a given file. But this command goes through all lines of the file, doesn't it?..